# Unknown SOT23 IC without matching code?

Tags: surface-mount

I'm trying to pick apart a signal conditioning board. I found a SOT23-6 package marked "4DLB" which doesn't seem to have any matching SMD code in any charts I found.

I suspect it may be a type of multiple diode(s) package given the rectification application. Is there any other way to ID this chip? No searches for the IC in any databases I am aware of returned useful results.

Hoping to use techniques discussed here for future hunts.

Added image: [image: https://ibb.co/YLXtBFP]

Thanks

Comment: *EDIT* Took better photo: https://ibb.co/7NT7GBM

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it's a Nexperia [PRTR5V0U4D](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PRTR5V0U4D.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have added a photo to the OP.

Comment: How did you go about searching to find this part? Pure experience?

Comment: Didn't fit the common part numbers for Schottky and regular diode arrays in SOT23-6.